# What is the effect of donating to the Great Rupee Fairy?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

The Great Rupee Fairy in *The Legend of Zelda: A Link Between Worlds* is found in Lorule, next to the Bomb Flower shop. What are the effects of donating to her, and how much (or how many times) does one need to donate to get those effects?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After donating a total of 3000 rupees, the great fairy will give you a bottle. Donating will also increase the number of fairies in the pond, which you can collect with your sword or the Butterfly Net

Answer (score 1):

I donated something over 2,000 Rupees (200 each time) and I got the following:

As this progresses more fairies are spawned each time, for a maximum of 5.

> She also gives Link an `Empty Bottle`.